# Alternative to retrieve data from "Query.prototype.exec()"?

Tags: mongoose

I was trying to console.log() some data from my posts collection using Mongoose, but turns out it no longer accepts a callback function from the ".exec()" method, so what would be an alternative for this?

Here I was accessing my variable "posts" which holds my posts model (with "mongoose.model('Posts', schema)"):

```
posts.find({}).sort({'_id': -1}).exec((err, posts) => {
    console.log(posts[0]);
});
```

And here's the error:
`throw new MongooseError('Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
posts.find({}).sort({'_id': -1}).then((data)=>{console.log(data)}).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
```

Comment: or you can use async await
var data = await posts.find({}).sort({"_id":-1}).exec()